# Show me a badge in the navbar under certain VueJS pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am building a SPA with Vue 3 and now I have the case that I would like to show a badge in the navbar of certain pages.
**My structure:**

```html
// App.vue
<template>
  <NavBar />
  <RouterView />
</template>
```

**My paths:**

- "/"
- "/faq"
- "counter/x" => **here i need the badge in the navbar**
- "counter/y" => **here i need the badge in the navbar**

I also use a simple store solution. Here I have a function

```js
export const store = reactive({
  isCounterPage: false,

  checkIsCounterPage() {
   this.isCounterPage = window.location.pathname.includes("/counter/");
  }
}
```

In the router/index.js File, I call the `checkIsCounterPage()` method.

```js
// router/index.js
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  store.checkIsCounterPage()
}
```

And in my navbar, I use a condition where i check the variable:

```html
// someView.vue
<template>
  <div v-if="store.isCounterPage" class="badge">BADGE</div> 
</template>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work the way I want it to. Only after a hard refresh of the page *(for example F5 / refresh Page)* it recognises where it is. So the problem is that the store method is only called once on initialisation and not on route change as I assume.

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong and is this the right way at all?

Comment: Why are you not using a computed + vue-router path combo? It will be reactive that way.

Comment: @kissu Thank you! Can you paraphrase a little more how you mean it. i.e. roughly draw the structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can add meta field to your counter routes:

```
routes: [
  { path: '/counter/x', component: x, meta: { isCounterPage: true } },
  ...
],
```

and check meta:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.isCounterPage) store.checkIsCounterPage(true)
  next()
}
```

and in store:

```
export const store = reactive({
  isCounterPage: false,

  checkIsCounterPage(val = false) {
    this.isCounterPage = val
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had already thought of it in a similar way. But why I hadn't done that was because I didn't want to add the meta in all the routes. Which is onsolte with the default value of the function. so this is a good solution. Thanks to you.

Comment: @Max Pattern you are welcome mate :) btw If you have many conter routes, and small number of no-counter ones, you can reveret and put meta on them, ofc adjust functions then, cheers :)